# Android Spinner and ListView with ALL item

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, spinner, android-contentprovider

Helo.

I have the following requirement:

I have a list (ListView or Spinner depends on orientation) that shows all the projects in the database. This List works as a filter for the detail list of project associated data. This works fine (I use Loader and ContentProvider to get data). The Project list and Detail list are realised as separate fragments and communicate over the onProjectSelectedListener interface.

My requirement is: I need "ALL" as the first list item, to disable the filter and show all data (without project filter). How can I realise that (SQLite oder Android solution are welcome). The best i woud get onItemSelected a specific ID (e.g.: -100) for the "ALL"-Item.

**Now**

```
Project 1 (id: 1)
Project 2 (id: 2)
Project 3 (id: 3)
...
```

**Required**

```
ALL Projects (id: -100)
Project 1 (id: 1)
Project 2 (id: 2)
Project 3 (id: 3)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a union view on SQLite database.

```
CREATE
    VIEW all_projects AS
SELECT
    -100                    AS _id,
    'ALL'                   AS pj_name,
    'All Projects'          AS pj_comment,
    1                       AS pj_is_active,
    1                       AS pj_all
UNION
SELECT
    *,
    1                       AS pj_all
FROM
    projects
```

The content provider make the select on the view if **where** statement has "pj_all" column and on tabel, if not.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(where) && where.contains(COLUMN_WITH_ALL)) {
    queryBuilder.setTables(VIEW_ALL);
}
else {
    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) to combine your current `CursorAdapter` (I'm guessing?) and a new `ArrayAdapter<String>` that has your "All" option?

You can react to click events, etc. by simply extending `MergeAdapter` instead of your current `Adapter`.